# Chrome Media Query Glitch: Media Query firing too early

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

We have a major problem where for some reason Chrome is firing responsive Media Queries too early.
So instead of firing at 1000px, it fires around 984px. Max width/min width containing any value makes no difference. It's as though it's off by about 14 to 24px depending on factors only it understands.

There are also no conflicting queries that could be causing this (we tried it on 'fresh pages' in the project) and even nuked the main stylesheet, but the problem still persists. Also we're not doing anything funky by manipulating window/document or body widths, margins, scale/zoom with Javascript or CSS.

We're completely baffled by this one and have tried for a few days to fix + check Stackoverflow etc. but to no avail so far.

Code below:

```
div {
     background: orange;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Some things in place and background:

- This worked previously, however all of a sudden we're encountering this bug...
- It is happening in Chrome and Brave, but works fine in Edge and Firefox. We've tried several other machines and different versions of Chrome, but the issue persists. We can only guess that maybe something got introduced into the project that is causing this, but we are stumped as to what.
- Browser zoom is correct @ 100%
- Meta tag viewport is in place correctly
- Tried the 'decimal fix' like 1000.0px - but it doesn't work...
- Dev tool says that the window size is 1000px, but Chrome only fires the code at 983px or thereabouts
- Code works in a test file (with the same index/template that is in the project) and Chrome handles the media query 100% correctly
- React Solution with Bootstrap 4.5.3
- Worked before

Any ideas?
Is there a way that we can 'reset' Chrome's media queries or what are we missing?
Answers in other similar questions in StackOverflow do not appear to work which makes us think that this is maybe a separate issue or new bug?

Any help / insight is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you got a scrollbar (normally around 17px width)?

Comment: yeah, but it hasn't impacted the media query measurement before + other browsers are still handling the query correctly with no need to compensate...

Comment: This isn't a scrollbar problem. I also had those problems before, and I think it's a chrome bug or something. In those cases, I tried to close that page and reopen it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your meta tag is missing the content attribute with values: width=device-width, initial-scale=1?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

as far as i can recall chrome requires these attributes and values to work proper with custom media queries

### EDIT

After a discussing with @user2381937 in chat and reading some external resources:
https://inspirnathan.com/posts/2-media-query-inspector-chrome/

https://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/

we found that chrome and firefox differ in how they consider the width of the scrollbar when rendering the page. And that the way forward is either to swap query breakpoints to account for the offset or to make browser specific queries.

Comment: Thanks, but we already have this in place  and added minimum-scale as well, but no difference 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: Someone tried to add a decimal value to their mediaquery and it supposedly worked, perhaps give min-width: 1000.0px a try?

Comment: We tried that - and tried it again as well now, but no cigar, unfortunately...

Comment: Hm, weird. I opened up a jsfiddle and it works properly here https://jsfiddle.net/q0xokv4u/

Comment: Alright so it turns out it does not in fact work in the jsfiddle either. It was working for me because i had the device-screen-thingie checked in chrome developer tools. According to some other posts and resources chrome doesn't consider the scrollbar when managing media queries which makes it offset the query with the width of the scrollbar(https://newbedev.com/issue-with-css-media-queries-scrollbar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237958/discussion-between-max-strandberg-and-user2381937).

Comment: Honestly. this is the weirdest thing. As on our side, the scrollbar made no impact on the query before. If we set the media query to 930px, it fired at 930px - not less not more. No compensation needed. We know this as we had to match designs and fix responsive sets / ranges at exact pixels lots of times before in this project - using Chrome as primary browser.

Comment: Thanks to Max for the insight into why the capital F this is happening in Chrome/Brave. And thanks @Google for non-standard implementations. I thought those days of MS IE were far behind us, but guess not. So much for web-standards ($%^&EWQ)

Answer (score 0):

*I know it's an older question, but for anyone finding this via a search engine...*

I haven't done CSS in a while and lately I had to fix a bug, where the following rule was not executed anymore:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) { /* styles here */ }
```

What I found out was, that the viewport's width these days was displayed with two decimal places. So I updated my CSS as following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991.4999px) { /* styles here */ }
```

It worked again. I don't know if that's intended and I also didn't put too much effort into checking all the different browsers on all the different devices, so take it with a grain of salt.